# expected initializer before 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int32_t main()
{
    cout << "Hello\n";
}
```

This is my code and the code is running, but Visual Studio Code shows this squiggles line with the message

> expected initializer before 'std' gcc

which makes me conscious about my code.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` you should never use this line: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: `int32_t main() {` should be just `int main() {`

Comment: [Pro Tip] `main` **always** returns `int`.  **always**.

Comment: Since [your code runs](https://godbolt.org/z/Mf8hYK) and your question is specifically about a "squiggles line" -- what tool are you using that shows you this line?  The line is a product of that tool and you haven't mentioned what tool it is.

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `int32_t` to `int`

And [never use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/).

Comment: Suggestion: provide a reason why you shouldn't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?

Comment: Also: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/)